# Adding Checkbox inside an Flex Advanced Datagrid

Tags: apache-flex

How to enable CheckBox inside an Flex Advanced Datagrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112036/creating-a-column-of-radiobuttons-in-adobe-flex), replacing Radio Buttons with Checkboxes?