# Creating a column of RadioButtons in Adobe Flex

Tags: flex3, advanceddatagrid

I am having an un-predictable behavior of creating radio buttons in advancedDataGrid column using itemRenderer. Similar kind of problem has been reported at 
[Creating a column of RadioButtons in Adobe Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112036/creating-a-column-of-radiobuttons-in-adobe-flex). I tried to use the same procedure i.e. bind every radio button selectedValue and value attributes with the property specified in the property of the associated bean but still facing the problem.

> The button change values! The selected
>   button becomes deselected, and
>   unselected ones become selected.

Here is the code of my advancedDataGrid:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="adDataGrid_rptdata" 
                width="100%" height="100%"
                dragEnabled="false" sortableColumns="false" 
                treeColumn="{action}"
                liveScrolling="false"
                displayItemsExpanded="true" >

                <mx:dataProvider>
                    <mx:HierarchicalData source="{this.competenceCollection}" childrenField="competenceCriteria"/>
                </mx:dataProvider>

                <mx:columns>
                    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="" id="action" dataField="criteriaName" />

                    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Periode 1" dataField="" width="200">
                        <mx:itemRenderer>
                            <mx:Component>
                                <mx:HBox horizontalAlign="center" width="100%" verticalAlign="middle">                                  
                                    <mx:RadioButton name="period1" value="{data}" selected="{data.period1}" group="{data.radioBtnGrpArray[0]}" visible="{data.showRadioButton}" />
                                </mx:HBox>
                            </mx:Component>
                        </mx:itemRenderer>
                    </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>

                    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Periode 2" dataField="" width="200">
                        <mx:itemRenderer>
                            <mx:Component>
                                <mx:HBox horizontalAlign="center" width="100%" verticalAlign="middle">                                  
                                    <mx:RadioButton name="period2" value="{data}" selected="{data.period2}" group="{data.radioBtnGrpArray[1]}" visible="{data.showRadioButton}" />
                                </mx:HBox>
                            </mx:Component>
                        </mx:itemRenderer>
                    </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>

                    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Periode 3" dataField="" width="200">
                        <mx:itemRenderer>
                            <mx:Component>
                                <mx:HBox horizontalAlign="center" width="100%" verticalAlign="middle">                                  
                                    <mx:RadioButton name="period3" value="{data}" selected="{data.period3}" group="{data.radioBtnGrpArray[2]}" visible="{data.showRadioButton}" />
                                </mx:HBox>
                            </mx:Component>
                        </mx:itemRenderer>
                    </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>
                </mx:columns>
            </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

Any work around is highly appreciated in this regard!

Answer (score 0):

> The selected button becomes deselected, and unselected ones become selected.

Is this problem occurring only for those radio buttons whose `selected` state was manually changed by the user? In that case it is because flex resets its `selected` state based on the value mentioned in the declaration when a `RadioButton` is reused. So even if you select/deselect a ratio button in the Periode 1 column, flex resets it to `{data.period1}` when you scroll away and come back. Making the column editable to save the modifications back to the data provider might work. Try changing the column declaration to:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Periode 1" dataField="" width="200" 
     editable="true" rendererIsEditor="true" editorDataField="selected">
```

EDIT: Try this - attempting to change the data provider when the radio button is selected. code written from memory and not tested - might contain bugs.

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Periode 1" dataField="" width="200">
  <mx:itemRenderer>
    <mx:Component>
      <mx:HBox horizontalAlign="center" width="100%"
        verticalAlign="middle">
        <mx:RadioButton id="rb" name="period1" value="{data}" 
          selected="{data.period1}" 
          group="{data.radioBtnGrpArray[0]}" visible="{data.showRadioButton}" 
          change="outerDocument.handleRadio1(this);"/>
      </mx:HBox>
    </mx:Component>
  </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>
//in a script tag outside the datagrid.
public function handleRadio1(renderer:IListItemRenderer):void
{
  var index:Number = adDataGrid_rptdata.itemRendererToIndex(renderer);
  this.competenceCollection[i].period1 = renderer.rb.selected;
}
```

Comment: Nothing had happened. Same situation. 
Why flex resets the {data.period1} on scroll away and come back, though i explicitly changed the {data.period1} on the change event of RadioButtonGroup.

Comment: Flex recycles the itemRenderers. So if your list has 100 items but only 10 is visible at a time, flex creates 10 renderers and change their values as you scroll through the list. So the radio button that displayed 1st item will be used to display 11th one if the visible range is from 2 to 11. Flex changes the properties of itemRenderers using the set data method. So every time an item renderer is reused its set data method gets called and all properties will be reset as per the data. The solution is to change the data when you select a button

Comment: I have updated the post with code to change the data provider when radio button is clicked. See if it works.

Comment: This line is causing an error, renderer.rb.selected.
Renderer is unable to access rb property of the radiobutton.

Comment: Amarghosh bro? Any advise in this matter...? 
Just to let you know you have used change method of RadioButton, however in my code i tried to capture the value of radioButton using the RadioButtonGroup to which the buttons are asscoiated.

Comment: Try placing the itemRenderer in its own class.